# Contacts App RawContact editing

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a an app that creates raw contacts in the ContactsContract and aggregates them to existing contacts with some data (eg: Name, Email) added to it. These raw contacts show up in the Contacts app and when you click on edit contact the raw contacts appear. Now the Contacts app only allows editing of google related raw contact data. What I would like to happen is when a person clicks on my Raw Contact I would like my app to pop up. Maybe add a button to raw contact to show up in the Contacts app while I am at it (If that possible).

But the problem is I have no clue where to begin.

Help is Appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: -Just show your code what u have tried.

Comment: I can show you code where I add the raw contacts to the contact list, but anything related to the above question I don't have simply because I don't know what to do. The obvious google search didn't reveal anything either, so basically I am stuck

Comment: No one wants to answer this?